# gulp-notify does not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir, gulp-notify

After formatting my Mac and installing the Laravel Valet environment my gulp-notify stopped to work!

That is the message:

[image]

Somebody knows how to fix it?

BTW I am using Laravel 5.2 + Elixir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed!

Deleted node_modules folder and run `npm i` again =)